# proper way to fail test when find_index returns nil with page_objects

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I am using find_index to find an element and then click on its link. However when the index returns nil, it clicks on the link for element 0. Is there a proper way to fail this?

Here is my code:

```
def index_for(fruit)
   index = fruits_elements.find_index{|f| f.div_element.text == fruit}
   index
end
def click_on_product(fruit)
  index = index_for(fruit)
  fruits_element[index.to_i].link_element.click
end
```

Ideally I would like it to fail if not found. Currently it clicks on element 0 when nil is returned. As always your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do change as below

```
def click_on_product(fruit)
  index = index_for(fruit)
  begin
  # will throw type error, when index is nil.
  fruits_element[index].link_element.click
  rescue TypeError => ex
    # any exception related message if you want to print
    # should be here.
  end
end
```

> However when the index returns nil, it clicks on the link for element 0. Is there a proper way to fail this?

See, you used `index.to_i`, in the line `fruits_element[index.to_i].link_element.click`. Now, [`NilClass#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i) method, actually returning `0`. Because `nil.to_i` is `0`. Thus `fruits_element[index.to_i]` is actually became `fruits_element[0]`, which is the first element, that was getting click as you reported.

As you want to raise error, just don't use `to_i` method there.

[`find_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index) method either returns *integer* when found, or `nil` when not found. I think as per your code, there is no need to convert an *integer* to again *integer*, as you are interested to throw error.

You should also write the method `index_for` as below.

```
def index_for(fruit)
   fruits_elements.find_index {|f| f.div_element.text == fruit }
end
```

You don't need to write the variable `index` as a last expression to return it. Because in Ruby, *last expression of a method by default returned.*

Comment: The `index =` part of the `index_for` method could also be removed, right?